# Failed to load gds32.dll

Tags: firebird

I have Firebird 1.5 data, my windows is 64 bit, then I want to make ODBC between it, but it when I test its connection always failed (failed to load gds32.dll), and I already copied gds32.dll into Windows/System32, but it is same failed reason. I already installed firebird 1.5 service, and it always runs.

Could somebody helped me?

Comment: In 64 bit Windows copy gds32.dll to : `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`

Comment: can't copy into SysWow64, because it is using with another process, what is the solution?

Comment: Are you using a 32 bit or 64 bit ODBC driver, which gds32.dll did you copy to System32 (note that on 64 bit windows, System32 is for **64 bit dlls**, 32 bit dlls go into SysWOW64).

Comment: Relevant: http://support.brainwaregroup.com/kb/article/AA-00486/0/HOW-TO%3A-Create-an-ODBC-connection-to-the-Firebird-database.html